# Web push notifications for web version of Expo project?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, service-worker, react-native-web

I'm working on an expo project and I want to add push notification functionality for the web version (which builds with [React Native Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web)). I'm specifically talking about implementing push notifications that can be sent to users who only use the project in a browser, whether mobile, desktop, or anything in between.

I can't find any info about using service workers or implementing web-push notifs with React Native Web or Expo.

Is there a way to implement web-push functionality for just the RN Web version of my project (preferably alongside Expo push notifs, which will be for the native versions)?

Answer (score 3):

the web notifications are in pending status in the new notifications api, I hope that in the near future the notifications will work by default.
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Maybe you can try to do as follow:

- use react-onesignal component specific for web (https://github.com/pedro-lb/react-onesignal#readme), see platform specific code: https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/react-native/platform-specific-code/
- save to db the onesignal.playerId
- check if playerId exist and send notification to it using onsignal api.
- continue tu use standard push notifications for ios and android